# calculate the median by excluding outliers (+-25% of median of four columns) for values of four columns values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, median

I have four columns containing the amount of unit sold in last 4 years. I want to calculate the median and then calculate the mean by excluding the column values based on condition (+-25% of median).

```
df = df[['Date','ID','amount']] # df has daily data

df['dayofYear'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofyear

df['Year_Lag1']= df.groupby(['ID','dayofYear'])['amount'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1))

df['Year_Lag2']= df.groupby(['ID','dayofYear'])['amount'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(2))

df['Year_Lag3']= df.groupby(['ID','dayofYear'])['amount'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(3))

df['Year_Lag4']= df.groupby(['ID','dayofYear'])['amount'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(4))


df['YearLag_median']= df[['Year_Lag1','Year_Lag2','Year_Lag3','Year_Lag4']].median(axis=1) #median amount on same date (is there a better way to calculate median by avoiding outliers)
```

how to calculate the average by avoiding values in four columns that lies in +- 25% of median.

suppose `Year_Lag1 = 5000, Year_Lag2= 230, Year_Lag3=4500, Year_Lag4= 4300`.

how to calculate average by avoiding `Year_Lag2` value.

I want this to be done for all rows in a dataframe.

(also if someone can help with a better way to calculate median by avoiding outliers)
Data set[data has values for 2nd and 3rd january (2014,15,16,17,18). Year_Lag1(shift(1)) has values from previous year for 2nd and 3rd jan. Year_Lag2(shift(2) has values from last to last year)  so on..]

last row is the example where I want to ignore 589.0 to calculate the mean.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Dvp.png`enter code here`

Comment: Is the +-25 % calculated for each row or on the overall rows ?

Comment: it has to be for each row

Comment: As suggested in one answer, it would be good if you could share a sample of your dataframe

Comment: I have added image for the reference. Please refer the last row for the exact example of the concerned scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, I think there should be something better to do it, but still it works:

1. Define a function to calculate the mean according to your specifications

```
def calculateMean(row):
    s = 0
    n = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if ~np.isnan(row[i]) and abs(row[i] - row[-1]) < 0.25 * row[-1]:
            s += row[i]
            n += 1
    return (s/n if n else np.nan)
```

2. Apply this function on every rows

```
df["YearLag_mean"] = df.loc[:, ['Year_Lag1','Year_Lag2','Year_Lag3','Year_Lag4', 'YearLag_median']]\
                       .apply(lambda row: calculateMean(row), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
            Date   ID  amount  dayofYear  Year_Lag1  Year_Lag2  Year_Lag3  Year_Lag4  YearLag_median  YearLag_mean
2258  2014-01-02  200  1778.0          2        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN             NaN           NaN
2259  2014-01-03  200  2149.0          3        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN             NaN           NaN
2623  2015-01-02  200  2057.0          2     1778.0        NaN        NaN        NaN          1778.0       1778.00
2624  2015-01-03  200  2401.0          3     2149.0        NaN        NaN        NaN          2149.0       2149.00
2988  2016-01-02  200  2315.0          2     2057.0     1778.0        NaN        NaN          1917.5       1917.50
2989  2016-01-03  200   589.0          3     2401.0     2149.0        NaN        NaN          2275.0       2275.00
3354  2017-01-02  200  1709.0          2     2315.0     2057.0     1778.0        NaN          2057.0       2050.00
3355  2017-01-03  200  1659.0          3      589.0     2401.0     2149.0        NaN          2149.0       2275.00
3719  2018-01-02  200  1991.0          2     1709.0     2315.0     2057.0     1778.0          1917.5       1964.75
3720  2018-01-03  200  1570.0          3     1659.0      589.0     2401.0     2149.0          1904.0       1904.00
```

As you can see, the last row didn't use `589` but also `2401` because of your threshold.

To remove outliers instead of using the median, you can look at IQR or Z-score, but I'm not sure it works well on small data, you can give it try and just adapt or create new functions.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Rightly said for median I need to check for better way to remove outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you could add a dataframe for reference. Tried generating a df as you've specified below by generating random dates in this year, random float amounts and random IDs. A 5-row head of my df looks like this:

```
df.head(5)
   amount                          Date   ID
0      93 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  AAA
1      40 2019-01-03 08:43:38.181818181  AAA
2      47 2019-01-05 17:27:16.363636363  BBB
3      37 2019-01-08 02:10:54.545454545  CCC
4      13 2019-01-10 10:54:32.727272727  CCC
```

Is this what your dataset looks like? 
If so then running the commands you've mentioned to get lags don't seem to work as expected. When i run it I get this as mentioned below:

```
df['dayofYear'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofyear
df.head(5)
                           Date   ID  amount  dayofYear
0 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  AAA      93          1
1 2019-01-03 08:43:38.181818181  AAA      40          3
2 2019-01-05 17:27:16.363636363  BBB      47          5
3 2019-01-08 02:10:54.545454545  CCC      37          8
4 2019-01-10 10:54:32.727272727  CCC      13         10

df['Year_Lag1']= df.groupby(['ID','dayofYear'])['amount'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1))
df.head(5)
                           Date   ID  amount  dayofYear  Year_Lag1
0 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  AAA      93          1        NaN
1 2019-01-03 08:43:38.181818181  AAA      40          3        NaN
2 2019-01-05 17:27:16.363636363  BBB      47          5        NaN
3 2019-01-08 02:10:54.545454545  CCC      37          8        NaN
4 2019-01-10 10:54:32.727272727  CCC      13         10        NaN
```

Have made sure that the head is not the only one with nans. The whole column gets nans. If you could modify your original post to include a df it would make it a lot easier to answer your question.